# Recommended View Types for UI

Tags: android, android-listview

I am new to Android Dev and I am looking to implement an app which operates similar to the facebook app (i.e. a menu on the left). If a menu item is tapped, a view slides in from the right. From what I have read, it would appear that I need to use:

- A horizontal scrollview containing the menu view (master) and the selected view (detail)
- The menu view and the selected view should be list views

Would this be the right approach to achieve this UI, or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html). The Android training site has a guide for [Creating a Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) using the supplied `DrawerLayout`, which does all the hard work for you.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this library: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

it supports both sliding menus from the left and right sides (by swiping).